# Почему в этом методе лучше полиморфизм?

Tags: ооп, полиморфизм

Читаю книгу "*Совершенный код*", проходя раздел автор привел пример метода, который лучше было бы заменить полиморфизмом:

```
switch (shape.type) {
    case Shape_Circle:
        shape.DrawCircle();
        break;
    case Shape_Square:
        shape.DrawSquare();
        break;
    ...
}
```

Цитата из книги: "*Здесь методы shape.DrawCircle() и shape.DrawSquare() следует заменить на единственный метод shape.Draw(), поддерживающий рисование и окружностей, и прямоугольников.*"

Не могу понять, смысл от создания нового метода, если все равно придется писать оператор `switch` в другом методе, можете подробнее объяснить, чем такой подход лучше?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public abstract class Shape
{
  public abstract void Draw();
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
  public override void Draw()
  {
    // implement drawing of a circle
  }
}

public class Square : Shape
{
  public override void Draw()
  {
    // implement drawing of a square
  }
}

public class SomeUnforeseenShape : Shape
{
  public override void Draw()
  {
    // draw Mona Lisa
  }
}


public void DrawShape(Shape shape)
{
  shape.Draw();
}
```

Comment: Хм... Действительно... Спасибo! :D Сейчас 6 минут пройдет и приму ответ.