# Как на практике применяется полиморфизм?

Tags: java, ооп, полиморфизм, инкапсуляция

Вот само теоретическое понятие инкапсуляции легко запомнить - сокрытие данных - потому что это применяется на практике, геттеры, сеттеры, приватные методы и переменные и т.п. А как на практике применяется полиморфизм? Уверен, что я его все время использую, но не знаю об этом. Может, когда узнаю, быстро запомню.

**РЕД:** Правильно ли я понимаю, что полиморфизм - это переопределение/перегрузка методов(и все?)?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498887/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC/498888#498888

Comment: Когда создаёшь перегруженный метод. Получается он может принимать данные разных типов.

Comment: Нет, не правильно. Перегрузка методов не имеет никакого отношения к полиморфизма.

Comment: Точно @not заметил)

Comment: Помимо ответов о том что полиморфизм, может быть реализован путем переопределения методов в классах "наследниках", это еще и реализация одного и того же интерфейса, необязательно, чтобы классы были "родственные". Вообще-то, это общий вопрос и такие вопросы закрывают, так как на эту тему есть много книг по ООП.

Comment: @yury Вопрос нормальный, на самом деле мало кто понимает суть и само явление полиморфизма, поскольку он по разному реализован в языках программирования.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Полиморфизм - это свойство объекта менять своё поведение во время выполнения. Во время компиляции вызов метода переадресовывыется к классу, который его содержит, а во время выполнения к классу из которого он был создан. Вы  часто используете родительские классы и интерфейсы для определения типа переменной, но создаете объекты подклассов и присваивание ссылку этой переменной.

Например так:

```
 Parent variable = new Child();
```

Эта переменная может вызывать только методы, определённые в родительском классе, но если эти методы перекрыты в подклассе, то вызов метода переадресовывается в подкласс, в котором этот метод перекрыт.

И поскольку родительский класс может иметь множество подклассов, в которых имеются виртуальные методы с такой же сигнатурой, перекрытые в родительском классе, и имеющими свою имплементацию, то вы можете присваивать переменной объект любого из этих подклассов, и тогда будет вызван соответствующий метод подкласса, несмотря на то что в родительском классе этот метод имеет свою имплементацию.

Практически, интерфейсы и абстрактные методы *чисто виртуальные*, потому что не имеют имплементации, и использование их в коде приводит к полиморфизму, поскольку их имплементация находится в подклассах.

На практике мы часто расширяем классы и подменяем изначальную имплементацию на другую и хотим, чтобы оно работало. И поскольку оно ничего не знает о наших объектах, то вызывает свои методы не имея ни малейшего понятия, что на самом деле выполнялось. Такой подход часто применяется при тестировании, когда вам нужно изменить поведение объектов, за счёт того что вы используете заготовки в рантайме, и подставляете их вместо реальных объектов.

Comment: ничего не понятно...

Comment: что тебе не понятно?

Comment: Все понятно, отличный ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Допустим, мы пишем генератор отчетности. У нас есть некий класс, который принимает на вход один из отчетов и выполняет его построение. Отчеты у нас разные, но, в общем-то, последовательность их построения одна и та же:

```
public class ReportBuilder {
   public ReportBuilder() {
   }

   public createReport(Report report) {
      data = report.collectData();
      excelFile = this.makeExcel(report, report.template());
      this.publishAndSave(excelFile); 
   }
}
```

Наш класс `ReportBuilder` запрашивает данные у класса отчета, размещает их в Excel, запросив у класса отчета шаблон, и сохраняет результат.

Теперь мы можем создать разные классы отчета, которые обладают своими шаблонами своей логикой сбора данных:

```
abstract class Report {
   DataContainer collectData();
   String template()
}

class ReportA extends Report {
   DataContainer collectData() {
      // собираем одни данные
   }

   String template() {
      return 'file1.xls';
   }
}

class ReportB extends Report {
   DataContainer collectData() {
      // собираем другие данные
   }

   String template() {
      return 'file1.xls';
   }
}
```

После этого мы можем делать вот так:

```
reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder();
reportBuilder.createReport(new ReportA());
reportBuilder.createReport(new ReportB());
```

Таким образом:

- Общую логику построения отчетов мы разместили в `ReportBuidler` : он отвечает за работу с Excel, сохранение и публикацию отчета.
- Логика, отвечающая за сбор данных, расположена в классе каждого отчета.
- И **полиморфизм** - это то, что позволяет передавать объекты разных классов в метод `createReport()` и быть уверенным, что в нем вызовутся методы `collectData()` и `template()` соответствующего класса.

Answer (score 0):

делится на переопределение и перегрузку
переопределение - это когда ты объявляешь абстрактные методы в абстрактных классах/интерфейсах, а потом переопределяешь их в первом же классе наследнике/имплементации.
перегрузка - это при наличии методов с одинаковым возвращаемым типом и названием, но разными входными параметрами они считаются различными методами и работают, тем самым метод перегружается.

Answer (score 0):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что полиморфизм - это переопределение/перегрузка методов(и все?)?

Нет, неправильно. Это как бы необходимое условие. Да, в Java перегрузка метода является полиморфизмом - то есть в Java все методы полиморфные, а скажем в С++ это не так. Перегрузка метода не тождественна полиморфности. В C++ есть еще ключевое слово `virtual`, то есть нужно, чтобы метод был еще обозначен как виртуальный, только тогда он будет обладать полиморфизмом.

Самый простой пример полиморфизма, это то что все прогеры бессознательно используют -  метод `Object.toString()`, например:

```
class Child {
   private int age;

   @Override
   String toString() {
      return "age is "+age;
   }
}


Child child=new Child();
Object myObject=child;
System.out.println(child);  //печатаем объект Child
System.out.println(myObject);  //печатаем объект Object
```

Выдача в обоих случаях будет одинаковой. Если бы не было полиморфизма, выдача в первом случае была бы:

> age is 4

Во втором случае:

> Object@456

то есть хэш значение объекта

Но благодаря полиморфизму - выдача одинакова.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, многое прояснили