# Пример полиморфизма в Java из книги Философия Java

Tags: java, полиморфизм

```
    public class Example {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Circle circle = new Circle();
            Triangle triangle = new Triangle();
            Line line = new Line();

            circle.doSomething(circle); //круг
            triangle.doSomething(triangle); //треугольник
            line.doSomething(line); //линия
        }
}
```

Class Line

```
public class Line extends Shape {

}
```

Class Circle

```
public class Circle extends Shape {

}
```

Class Triangle

```
public class Triangle extends Shape  {

}
```

Class Shape //Фигура

```
public class Shape {

    public void erase() {
        System.out.println("Cтирать");
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Рисовать");
    }

    void doSomething(Shape shape) {
        shape.erase();
        shape.draw();
    }
}
```

Весь пример в книге не описан, поэтому я всё создал сам смотря пример в книге. Проверьте пожалуйста правильный ли он? 
Нужны ли перенести методы: `erase, draw` в отдельный интерфейс именно в данном примере?
 Это и есть полиморфизм, так как мы используем тип и параметр класса Shape в методе `Shape shape` и нам без разницы какая фигура будет параметром?

Comment: Полиморфизм - это фитча, которая позволяет объектам наследникам изменять своё поведение, т.е. вести себя по своему, не так как это делали предки.

Comment: @RomanC но то что вы сказали это же переопределение метода, разве нет?

Comment: Д, так и есть, см также https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/935433/204920

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как Вам уже ответили в [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/938426/192978), нужно переопределять методы для каждого класса наследника.

Однако, класс `Shape` может вообще не иметь этих методов и никак их не реализовывать. Почему? Все просто, потому что каждая фигура по своему может реализовывать рисование: для рисования окружности нужно знать ее центр и радиус, для прямоугольника обычно используют координаты левого верхнего угла и его размеры (ширина + высота). И никто же не говорит, что фигуры обязаны быть только двумерными (а как же сферы, кубы, эллипсоиды, гиперболоиды и пр... они все рисуются намного сложнее). Класс `Shape` просто не может знать и реализовать **все виды** перерисовок всех возможных фигур.

Для этого существуют интерфейсы. С их помощью можно указать программе, что некоторая сущность (в нашем случае фигура) **может что-то делать** (в нашем случае стираться и рисоваться), **но не знать, как именно** она будет это делать.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/*
 * Интерфейсы, показывающие "что мы можем делать"
 */
interface Drawable {
    void draw();
}

interface Eraseable {
    void erase();
}

/*
 * абстрактный класс фигуры
 * участок кода `implements Drawable, Eraseable` якобы говорит, что
 * "Фигура умеет рисоваться и стираться",
 * но фигура сама по себе не знает, КАК ИМЕННО она это будет делать
 */
abstract class Shape implements Drawable, Eraseable {
    public void doSomething() {
        erase();
        draw();
    }
}

/*
 * Классы конкретных фигур, которые "говорят" программе, 
 * КАК ИМЕННО они будут рисоваться и стираться
 */
class Triangle extends Shape {
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Triangle::draw");
    }

    public void erase() {
        System.out.println("Triangle::erase");
    }
}


class Circle extends Shape {
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Circle::draw");
    }

    public void erase() {
        System.out.println("Circle::erase");
    }
}

/*
 * И самое вкусное в классе Main
 */
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // список каких-то фигур.. мы не знаем, каких. Нам все равно.
        // мы просто знаем, что у нас есть фигуры
        ArrayList<Shape> list_of_shapes = new ArrayList();

        // добавляем конкретные фигуры в список "каких-то" фигур
        list_of_shapes.add(new Circle());
        list_of_shapes.add(new Triangle());
        list_of_shapes.add(new Circle());

        // работаем со списком, не задумываясь, КАКИЕ ИМЕННО у нас фигуры
        for (Shape shape : list_of_shapes) {
            shape.doSomething();
        }

        System.out.println("CLOSE PROGRAM");

        for (Shape shape : list_of_shapes) {
            shape.erase();
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге получаем следующий вывод на экран (обратите внимание, что вызываются методы классов `Circle` и `Triangle`, хотя в цикле перечисляется `Shape`):

```
Circle::erase
Circle::draw
Triangle::erase
Triangle::draw
Circle::erase
Circle::draw
CLOSE PROGRAM
Circle::erase
Triangle::erase
Circle::erase
```

Однако логичный вопрос: в чем же тут полиморфизм? Ведь вопрос был про него. Обратите внимание на метод `main`. Самое прелестное там то, что в **список каких-то фигур** мы добавляем **конкретные** фигуры (окружности и треугольники). Пример - векторный графический редактор. Пользователь набросал в окне редактора какие-то фигуры. Мы не знаем какие. И на этапе написания программы мы не можем знать. Однако, при закрытии программы нам нужно удалить все фигуры, стереть их. Метод `main` демонстрирует то, как можно вызывать методы конкретных классов, не зная о том, какой именно это класс.

В этом в принципе и есть вся суть полиморфизма (полиморфизм: от греч. *πολὺ*- — много, и *μορφή* — форма, или по-русски "многоформенность"). Используя знание о том, что мы работаем с *фигурой*, мы подставляем туда фигуру конкретной формы.

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно в каждом наследнике переопределить методы erase() и draw().

Да, это полиморфизм, в зависимости от типа, который вы передадите в метод doSomething() будет выбрана соответствующая реализация методов erase() и draw().

```
public abstract class Shape {
    abstract void erase();
    abstract void draw();
}

public class Circle extends Shape {
    void erase() {
        System.out.println("Circle");
    {
    void draw() {
        System.out.println("DrawCircle");
    }
}
```

Аналогично для других наследников.

Comment: Обязательно ли нужно переопределить эти методы чтобы можно было назвать это полиморфизмом или можно не переопределять?

Comment: Скорее всего да, просто если не переопределять, то будут вызываться методы родителя.

Comment: Это никакой не полиморфизм, а только желание его реализовать. Вот если бы линия, окружность и 3угольник были объявлены как Фигура, а реализованы соответствующим образом с реализацией своих методов рисования/стирания, тогда это мог бы быть полиморфизм.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Я же писал: "Проверьте пожалуйста правильный ли он? ". Напишите пожалуйста ваш пример чтобы я мог понять и увидеть потому что по вашим словам я понял половину если честно :)

Comment: так если он переопределит erase и draw все равно будут вызваны методы класса родителя!

Comment: @Олексiй Моренець , человек только учится, вообще полиморфизм трудно быстро понять на начальных этапах.

Comment: @Санаев, откройте ide и проверьте

Comment: @Vennic не увидел что он родитель... ну в принципе да... да и вообще shape лучше в таком случае делать абстрактным классом или интерфейсом

Comment: @Санаев, это то да, просто человеку вообще нужно понять смысл полиморфизма, а как его реализовать лучше всего, этому со временем научится.

Comment: @Vennic можете пожалуйста свой правильный пример полиморфизма в ответ добавить, чтобы я мог посмотреть?

Comment: @Петровченко Иван, добавил.

Comment: @Vennic обязательно делать абстрактным? Знаю что наследники вынуждены будут реализовывать методы родителя, но не очень понимаю в отличии от простого класса в плане полиморфизма

Comment: @Петровченко Иван,  сам по себе класс Shape дает общие понятия, абстракцию. Как допустим есть класс Фигура, мы знаем что для любой фигуры можно вычислить периметр и т.д., но сам объект класса Фигура на незачем, нет смысла его создавать. Поэтому он абстрактный, где есть методы , которые должны быть у конкретных фигур. А вот наследники этого класса, Треугольник, Круг и т.д., это уже конкретные классы, где каждый имеет свою реализацию методов. И если наследоваться от класса Фигура, мы будем уверены, что там будут методы для расчета периметра и т.д.

Comment: @Vennic спасибо большое

Comment: Ну вот не поленился и полез читать Экеля... Оказывается, автор нас немного обманул. Метод `doSomething(Shape s)` не принадлежит классам-наследникам, а просто является `stand-alone` и просто вызывает внутри себя методы `фигуры`, переданной в параметре.

Answer (score 1):

Если по книге, то должно быть примерно так

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle();
        Line line = new Line();

        doSomething(circle); // круг
        doSomething(triangle); // треугольник
        doSomething(line); // линия
    }

    private static void doSomething(Shape shape) {
        shape.erase(); // стереть
        shape.draw(); // нарисовать
    }
}

class Shape {

    public void erase() {
        System.out.println("Shape - erase");
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Shape - draw");
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape {

    public void erase() {
        System.out.println("Circle - erase");
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Circle - draw");
    }
}

class Triangle extends Shape {

    public void erase() {
        System.out.println("Triangle - erase");
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Triangle - draw");
    }
}

class Line extends Shape {

    public void erase() {
        System.out.println("Line - erase");
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Line - draw");
    }
}
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупые вопросы, как вы поняли что метод doSomething(Shape shape) должен быть приватным так и еще не в классе Shape, а в классе Main?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван он больше нигде не вызывается, `IDEA` сама по умолчанию предложила... И вообще - почему бы и нет? ))) Можете вполне сделать как в книге.