# java полиморфизм

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, полиморфизм

> Использование дочернего класса в качестве родительского класса

*Важным аспектом полиморфизма является возможность использовать объект дочернего класса, где ожидается объект его родительского класса.
Один из способов сделать это явно - создать экземпляр объекта дочернего класса в качестве члена родительского класса.*

**Теперь вопрос**

ЗАчем

```
Noodle biangBiang = new Spaghetti();
```

если мы можем написать и результат получим один и тот же

```
Spaghetti biangBiang = new Spaghetti();
```

Пример всего кода

```
class Noodle {

  protected double lengthInCentimeters;
  protected double widthInCentimeters;
  protected String shape;
  protected String ingredients;
  protected String texture = "brittle";

  Noodle(double lenInCent, double wthInCent, String shp, String ingr) {

    this.lengthInCentimeters = lenInCent;
    this.widthInCentimeters = wthInCent;
    this.shape = shp;
    this.ingredients = ingr;

  }

  public String getCookPrep() {

    return "Boil noodle for 7 minutes and add sauce.";

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Noodle n = new Noodle(30.0, 0.2, "round", "semolina flour");
    System.out.println(n.getCookPrep());
    Spaghetti a = new Spaghetti();
    System.out.println(a.getCookPrep());


  }

}

class Spaghetti extends Noodle {

  Spaghetti() {

    super(30.0, 0.2, "round", "semolina flour");

  }

  public String getCookPrep() {

    return "Boil spaghetti for 8 - 12 minutes and add sauce, cheese, or oil and garlic.";

  }

}
```

Объясните принцип полиморфизма, я его как бы понял, но видимо не со всем раз спрашиваю данный вопрос, и желательно пример,и хорошую статью и задание на тему полиморфизм. Спасибо.

Comment: Например тебе надо приготовить 100 видов спагетти Ты просто делаешь List с типом `Noodle` и помещаешь туда и `Spaghetti`и 99 остальных видов. А потом циклом пробегаешься по списку вызывая `getCookPrep`. В итоге, за счет этого тебе всё равно какого конкретно типа макароны - главное, что они приготовлены все. А теперь представь как бы ты это делал если бы писал Spaghetti biangBiang = new Spaghetti(); и так еще 99 видов и у каждого вызвать один метод?

Comment: Похожая тема уже обсуждалась [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/938448/192978)

Answer (score 8):

Например, для этого

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Noodle n = new Noodle(30.0, 0.2, "round", "semolina flour");        
    Spaghetti a = new Spaghetti();        

    printCookPrep(n);
    printCookPrep(a);
}

public static void printCookPrep(Noodle n){
    System.out.println(n.getCookPrep());
}
```

Comment: совсем не понял!

Comment: @FCAndroidFC благодаря `Использованию дочернего класса в качестве родительского класса` метод `printCookPrep` может работать как с классом `Noodle` так и со всеми его наследниками.

Comment: чуть понял, в данном примере дочерный класс это Spaghetti, можете еще написать  примеры из реальной жизни исользуя полиморфизм

Comment: да без проблем. Вот это `System.out.println(n);` скомпилируется, так как `println` метод принимает `Object`, а в java все наследуется от `Object`

Comment: ну или ищите любой абстрактный класс в Java - везде, где его используют, везде применяется `Использование дочернего класса в качестве родительского класса` просто потому, что нельзя создать экземпляр абстрактного класса.

Answer (score 4):

Например, у вас имеется база данных сотрудников фирмы. В ней есть абстрактный класс "Сотрудник" (который имеет поля имя и зарплата, а также методы доступа к ним), и от него наследуются более конкретные "Менеджер", "Программист", "Уборщик" и т.д., которые имеют свои более специфические состояния и поведения.

И вот задача: вывести список всех сотрудников и их зарплату в один файл.

Для абстрактных классов можно создавать объектные переменные, но такие переменные должны ссылаться на объект неабстрактного класса. Если заранее собирать в список всех сотрудников, то такая задача решится за один обход коллекции.

```
public abstract class Employee {
    private String name;
    private Integer pay;

    public void setName(String aName) {
        name = aName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setPay(int value) {
        pay = value;
    }

    public Integer getPay() {
        return pay;
    }
}

public class Coder extends Employee {
    private String position;

    public Coder(String name, int pay, String _position) {
        setName(name);
        setPay(pay);
        setPosition(_position);
    }

    public void setPosition(String value) {
        position = value;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
}


public class Manager extends Employee {
    public Manager(String name, int pay) {
        setName(name);
        setPay(pay);
    } 
}

public class TEST {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Employee> employees = new LinkedList<Employee>();
        // Нанимаем менеджера
        employees.add(new Manager("John", 25000));
        // Нанимаем программиста
        Coder coder1 = new Coder("Nick", 30000, "Junior");
        employees.add(coder1);
        // Нанимаем ещё менеджера
        Manager manager1 = new Manager("Cameron", 25000);
        employees.add(manager1);
        // Выводим список всех сотрудников
        for (Employee current : employees) {
            System.out.println(current.getName() + " - " + current.getPay().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Вот пример реализации принципа полиморфизма, к объектам подкласса можно обращаться из ссылочных переменных их суперкласса. **НО** здесь например нельзя будет из коллекции вызвать метод *setPosition* для объекта класса *Coder*, так как класс *Employee* не имеет о нём понятия.

```
employees.get(1).setPosition("Middle"); //error: cannot find symbol

// правильное решение, однако для этого необходимо проверять, является ли данный объект коллекции объектом требуемого класса, например используя instanceof
Coder myCoder = employees.get(1);
myCoder.setPosition("Middle");
```

Могу посоветовать книгу Кей Хорстманна "Java Библиотека профессонала" том 1. В главе о "Наследование" об этом рассказывается подробнее и с примерами кода.