# Как объект одного типа ссылается на другой класс?

Tags: java, классы, объекты, методы

Предположим, у нас есть класс `Dog` и класс `Animal`.

Как понять работу этой строки?

```
Animal d = new Dog();
```

И в чем её различие с этой строкой?

```
Dog d = new Dog();
```

Comment: или можете скинуть ссылку на статью где это можно понять

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как на практике применяется полиморфизм?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/935362/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [java полиморфизм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1020471/java-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополню:

> Animal d = new Dog();

- Это называется Upcasting(от наследника к родителю) , мы приводим к классу родителя, поэтому нам будут доступны только ,то что есть в классе Animal(методы и свойства).

> Dog dogo = (Dog) d;

- Это называется Downcasting(от родителя к наследникам), мы привели к исходному классу. Теперь нам доступно все .
  В переменную типа Dog можно поместить Animal только в том случае ,если в переменной типа Animal  уже изначально находился экземпляр класса Dog как в примере выше.

Answer (score 0):

"Animal d = new Dog()" - переменной типа Animal присваивается значение нового объекта класса Dog. Обычно в таких примерах Dog наследует Animal. Это значит, что у всякого Dog есть все свойства Animal, и никаких ошибок при использовании d возникать не должно. Да, и это фундаментальный признак объектно-ориентированного программирования - полиморфизм.

"Dog d = new Dog()" - переменной типа Dog присваивается значение нового объекта класса Dog.

Различие в типе переменной.

Читайте любой учебник или документацию.

Answer (score -1):

читай - полиморфизм...
тут ещё можно приписать оператор `Instanceof` и тд и тп...

если ты уже изучал коллекции!??
не задавался вопросом почему в основном пишут

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

обращаясь к интерфейсу?
можно ещё вверх на ступеньку по иерархии наследования подняться
наследования по интерфейсу!

```
Iterable<?> iterable = new ArrayList<>();
```

ну и самый вверх)

```
Object someThing = new ArrayList<>();
```

почитай одну книжку

```
Мэтт Вайсфельд "Объектно-ориентированное мышление"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

там про ооп страниц 150, но, если вникнуть, всё поймёшь...

Comment: хорошо, почитаю