# В чём смысл полиморфизма при наследовании абстрактного класса?

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, полиморфизм

Не понимаю суть полиморфизма и наследования.
Есть класс родитель:

```
public abstract class AbstractPhone {
    private int year;

    public AbstractPhone(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public abstract void call(int outputNumber);
    public abstract void ring (int inputNumber);
}
```

Есть независимый класс, который обращается к методу класса родителя:

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void callAnotherUser(int number, AbstractPhone phone) {
        // вот он полиморфизм - использование в коде абстактного типа AbstractPhone phone!
        phone.call(number);
    }
}
```

Есть классы наследники:

```
public class ThomasEdisonPhone extends AbstractPhone {

    public ThomasEdisonPhone(int year) {
        super(year);
    }

    @Override
    public void call(int outputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Вращайте ручку");
        System.out.println("Сообщите номер абонента, сэр");
    }

    @Override
    public void ring(int inputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Телефон звонит");
    }
}

public class Phone extends AbstractPhone {

    public Phone(int year) {
        super(year);
    }

    @Override
    public void call(int outputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Вызываю номер" + outputNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public void ring(int inputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Телефон звонит");
    }
}

public class VideoPhone extends AbstractPhone {

    public VideoPhone(int year) {
        super(year);
    }
    @Override
    public void call(int outputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Подключаю видеоканал для абонента " + outputNumber );
    }
    @Override
    public void ring(int inputNumber) {
        System.out.println("У вас входящий видеовызов..." + inputNumber);
    }
  }
```

Есть главный класс, в котором вызываются объекты разных классов, после чего, при помощи метода `callAnotherUser`, класса `User` выводится на экран содержимое методов классов наследников

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractPhone firstPhone = new ThomasEdisonPhone(1879);
        AbstractPhone phone = new Phone(1984);
        AbstractPhone videoPhone=new VideoPhone(2018);
        User user = new User("Андрей");
        user.callAnotherUser(224466,firstPhone);
        // Вращайте ручку
        //Сообщите номер абонента, сэр
        user.callAnotherUser(224466,phone);
        //Вызываю номер 224466
        user.callAnotherUser(224466,videoPhone);
        //Подключаю видеоканал для абонента 224466
    }
}
```

Так вот, в чём суть всего этого, не проще ли создать в главном классе объект каждого класса и при помощи этих объектов вызвать нужные нам методы?
И для чего нужны абстрактные методы, если их в любом случае нужно реализовывать, не проще ли просто создавать нужные методы в каждом классе?

Comment: Можно, все....но какой вид после этого будет иметь код? Вы подумали о понятности или дальнейшей сопровождаеиости... Все это нужно, чтобы не писать 100500 непонятных строк, которые потом кроме вас никто не поймет

Comment: Смысл полиморфизма трудно понять без понимания как оно применяется на практике https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/935433/204920

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Полиморфизм нужен, чтобы работать с похожими классами с помощью одних и тех же функций.

**Абстрактный пример:** стационарные телефоны с трубкой уже редкость, но мы очень активно используем символ 📞 для обозначения телефона, а так же действий взять/положить трубку. Почему? Мы так привыкли. Если вы выросли не в изоляции от массовой культуры, вы точно знаете этот символ. Обычно даже не важно, на каком языке вы говорите - этот символ вам понятен.

**Вернёмся к вашему примеру:** вы работаете над проектом в команде продолжительное время. Все привыкли: если использовать метод *callAnotherUser(номер,модель)*, произойдёт вызов абонента через указанную модель телефона. 

    Теперь вы добавляете новую модель *public class IPhone extends AbstractPhone.* Новая модель внутри может быть очень похожа на предыдущие, а может быть совсем не похожа. Главное, что она точно следует описанию заявленного ранее *abstract class AbstractPhone.*

    В этот момент вся ваша команда уже знает, как  работать с новой моделью телефона: всё те же call и ring. Вам не нужно объяснять, как работать с новым классом. Никому не нужно разбираться во внутренних принципах работы новой модели телефона, чтобы просто использовать её.

Полиморфизм несёт вам удобство для продолжительной разработки, разработки крупных проектов или работы в команде.