# Как использовать метод класса-наследника, которого нет в классе-родителе?

Tags: java, ооп, полиморфизм

Почему когда я пытаюсь у класса - наследника вызвать метод, которого нет в классе-родителе вылезает ошибка? При создании объекта нужно использовать полиморфизм.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person man = new Man(); //polymorphism
        man.sayHello();         //hello
        man.doSomething();      //error
    }
}
class Person {
    void sayHello(){
        System.out.println("hello!");
    }
}
class Man extends  Person{
    void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("it is doing something");
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что так и задумано....... чтобы использовать методы непосредственно наследника - надо будет кастануть

Comment: То есть никакого иного способа нет? Через интерфейс или абстракцию тоже?

Comment: Если метода нет в родителе то причём тут интерфейс или абстракция?))

Comment: ну вдруг чудо произойдёт)

Comment: Все логично. Вы расширяете класс с помощью наследования.  doSomething это поведение характерное именно Man, то есть и вызвать вы его можете только на объекте Man. Для аналогии представьте себе класс "фигура", и куча наследников (квадрат, окружность и т.д.) И допустим у класса окружность есть метод getRadius. Как вы будете вызывать его на ФИГУРЕ, а не на ОКРУЖНОСТИ? ведь не у каждой фигуры есть радиусе. Как такой метод должен работать на квадрате?

Comment: @had0uken Вызывать можно свои методы и те, которые наследуются из класса родителя. Только для это надо пользоваться соответствующим типом.

Comment: @Vitaly У класса-родителя может быть много наследников, а также те, которые могут добавляться в будущем. Поэтому знать о том, какой метод будет добавлен невозможно, поэтому пользоваться можно лишь тем что было до того.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в классе родителя нет этого метода. Ты создаешь переменную типа `Person` в которую кладешь объект `Man`. `Person` знает только унаследованные методы

Просто создай метод в `Person`

```
void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAA");
    }
```

И посмотри тогда , что напечатает `man.doSomething()`

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает по причине того что у класса-родителя `Person` нет метода `doSomething()`

```
man.doSomething();      //error
```

---

Если непонятно как работает наследование, то попробуй объявить переменную типа класса-родителя.

```
Man man = new Man();
```

---

Для того чтобы работал полиморфизм, у обоих классов должен быть объявлен метод с одинаковой сигнатурой. В противном случае можно вызвать метод класса-родителя после приведения типа, но это не будет полиморфизмом.

Чтобы лучше понять что такое полиморфизм рекомендую почитать [Как на практике применяется полиморфизм?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/935433/204920).